# Basic Algerbra - Ratio between three numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing an analysis, of client contracts that contain the following factors:

- The per-unit license price (A)
- The initial order quantity (B)
- The recommended retail price (C)

What I'd like is a single figure that represents "How good of a deal" the client got, with the quality of the deal being a low license price in comparison to both the initial order quantity and recommended retail price.

Generally speaking,

- The per-unit price decreases as the initial order quantity increases.
- The per-unit price increases as the recommended retail price increases

However, as the contracts were often negotiated, there is a lot of deviation between the individual contracts.

How can I go about this? My math is embarrassingly super rusty.

Comment: Is it a per-item license, or a one-time license?  Is a high initial order quantity better than a low initial order quantity?  Do any of these factors have correlations to each other?